# Angular2 view does not scroll to top after route navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a simple link to navigate to another page, with HashLocationStrategy :

```
<a href="/#/mypage">My Page</a></div>
```

After clicking the link above, `mypage` is being loaded, but since I scrolled down the previous page it is loaded in the middle of the page (same scroll position of previous page).

I do have a workaround, but why is this happening?

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because there is no actual page refresh. There is no implementation yet on how to trigger this without using a workaround. I guess the main issue is that you can have multiple `router-outlet` in the same screen, and that in cases it should not scroll up.

Inside my `AppComponent` I use this workaround. You probably use the same:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this._router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you

Comment: I tried this but its not working for me as I have this block in my code,
html,body { 
overflow-x: hidden;
}
Removing this will solve issue but I can't remove it as it will affect other components. any other solution?

Comment: @khush the latest [angular (6.1.0)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features) has support for restoring scroll

Comment: but my now my project is on Angular v5

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to define on the target page:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyPageComponent {

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: corrected :) Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It works for me but I have to add this to each and every one of my components. Is there a way to make it apply globally? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because Angular prevents the default action for a link click event, therefore the page isn't scrolling to the top.

As a workarround just subscribe to `router.events` and filter out the NavigationEnd event:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if(event instance of NavigationEnd) {
     ... scroll to top
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I do have a workaround, but why is this happening?

One of the reasons why it's happening, or better to say: it isn't happening, because Angular2 router can be used to navigate just inside a given outlet. You can have many [named router outlets](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html) (or one somewhere lower in the page) and scrolling the page to top after navigating any of them would break the behavior. And as we can see adding the scroll functionality is not so hard to implement by yourself. Also worth to read: [Named router outlets in Angular2](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)